# EF 6 MVC db.savechanges() is not picking the newly added entity in model class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I'm stuck with this problem with couple of days now. looking for a breakthrough

1. Added new field in model class. `public string[] FacType { get; set; }`
2. Successfully added column in database table through EF migrations
3. Added references to `FacType` in create and edit method in controller
4. Issue is when during insert/edit operation through `db.SaveChanges()`, auto generated linq insert query doesn't have new column `FacType` in the definition

Code:

```
 db.Entries.Add(entry);
 db.SaveChanges();
```

Results in this SQL query

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[EntryId] AS [EntryId], 
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name],  
FROM 
    [dbo].Entries] AS [Extent1]
```

Comment: Why is FacType a string array? Is FactType supposed to be another table containing different FacTypes?

Comment: I can't believe that 2. is true. An array can't be mapped to a database column. EF really wouldn't migrate a database from that model.

Comment: Gert Arnold - I see EF can't manage complex types, I have not worked much on EF. Thanks for direction. I changed the type to String then it worked. But then I have to think of other way to store values as list/array.